# Reordering UITableViewCells (custom class). Cells reset to default once moved off-screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm developing an application in Objective-C for iOS, where reordering the cells is a needed function.

I am loading the data from a `plist`.

I don't want the user to be able to edit or delete the cells, so in `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`, I `return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone`.

I `return YES` in `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`.

And I implement `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath` as follows:

```
TableViewCell *cellToMove = self.reorderCells[fromIndexPath.row];

[self.reorderCells removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

[self.reorderCells insertObject:cellToMove
                        atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
```

In `TableViewController.h` I declare `self.reorderCells` as a pointer to an `NSMutableArray`.

However, after reordering, what happens is, while scrolling, the cell goes off-screen and is replaced by its default cell. The reordering is completely ignored. At one point it is possible to have a cell accidentally deleted/replaced and also to have 2 of the same cells on-screen.

**EDIT:**

I have created a custom cell class called `TableViewCell`. `self.reorderCells` adds a new cell object in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` every time. So it consists of only `TableViewCell`s.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your code above. Why is `cellToMove` an `NSString`? What is in `self.reorderCells`?

Comment: @AdamPro13 Sorry, that `NSString` is supposed to be `TableViewCell`; `self.reorderCells`, as said in the edit above, consists of `TableViewCell`s

Comment: you shouöd not hold any references to cells. you mess up memory management and cell re-use. instead save the indexPaths and think in rows, not cells.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I can't move the `indexPath`s around. I don't want the cell to be bound to the `indexPath`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the data in your data source when you move the cells.

For example, let's say you have an array called `cellNames` that you use to determine the content of each cell in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`. If `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` says you're moving cell 1 to cell 3, you need to edit `cellNames` so that your object at index 1 goes to object 3.

Comment: The array that contains all the cells is `self.reorderCells`. Do I have to make a new array that does the exact same thing?

Comment: You shouldn't need an array with all of your cells because the table view will manage that for you. What you should have is an array of objects you use to populate the cells. For example, let's say you're displaying a list of recipes. You would have an array of recipe objects that you use to populate each cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: The "array that is populating the cells" is split up into 3 arrays; the `TableViewCell` class has 3 properties: The `titleLabel` (`IBOutlet UILabel *`), `descriptionLabel` (also of same type as previous), `image` (`IBOutlet UIImageView *`). How would I implement your suggestion if I have 3 different arrays?

Comment: How are you determining what string to use for the `titleLabel`, `descriptionLabel`, and image for `image`?

Comment: It's all from the `plist`. I'm loading all the resources with the app. I'm using `[UIImage imageNamed:(NSString *)]` to set `image`.

Comment: I think that's your problem. You are moving the cells around, but you aren't editing their order in the plist.